# Prevent NSTableView / NSOutlineView from separating cells

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have a Mac app with a view-based `NSOutlineView`. The outline view seems to separate its rows so the background color of the nearest ancestor view with a background shows through. How do I prevent this? I've already set grid style to none.

Comment: Can you show an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There's a method called `setInterCellSpacing` on `NSTableView` that separates the cells. Mine was set to non-zero values. Set it to `NSZeroSize` and the issue goes away.